# Apple alias in Mail and iCloud revealing my identity

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, security, alias

I've set up a few email aliases in iCloud under pseudonyms.

If I receive an email to one of them (e.g. `"Alias Name <pseudonym@icloud.com>`), and I try to reply in Mail for Mac, it uses the right email address, but instead of putting "Alias Name" in the from field, it appends my real, full name:

```
Full Name <pseudonym@icloud.com>
```

No doubt that's very frustrating and unreliable.

In the drop-down, I can select `Alias Name <pseudonym@icloud.com>` but that's a hassle each time — I have already forgotten and compromised my pseudonym a few times.

What do you suggest? Is this a bug with my setup, or for everyone?

Comment: This is happening in OS X Lion for me, can anyone else replicate?

Comment: Does it show up in the reciever's end as well? Search for the address in your address book and remove it from any contacts and see if that helps.

Comment: @Emil yes it does :| and thanks, tried that with no luck — does it happen for you as well?

Comment: How did you set up your alias/synonym address? I'll see if I can replicate it.

Comment: @emil thanks; just through iCloud.com the standard way — but names on both are different

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to replicate this behaviour – when I click "Reply" in the native OS X Mail app, having All Inboxes selected, the address and correct alias name pops up. (If I only have the iCloud-inbox selected, it automatically replies from the main iCloud address..)

One thing you should do is double check the alias' settings on iCloud.com – specifically the alias name. If it's filled correctly, try to remove the iCloud (mail)account from your mac and relink it. If that doesn't fix it, go all the way and remove the actual alias from iCloud and make a new one, and try again. If even that doesn't fix it, throw your mac on the ground and walk away angrily. <sub><sup>(No, don't actually try that, it won't work)</sup></sub>

If nothing works, and you are unable to replicate this behaviour on a different computer, delete all settings and completely reset the Mail app.

Comment: I will try and report back — what OS do you have?

Comment: 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion).

Comment: Ah, I have Lion, maybe it's that — but will look into it

Comment: It could be, seems like an odd bug though.